# Show that there is no matrix B such that exp(B)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that there is no matrix $B$ such that

$$
\text{exp}(B) = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0   \\
0 & -2
\end{array}
\right]
$$

I'm trying to use the canonical form of jordan, but unfortunately I'm not able to.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Existence

Comment: I'm assuming $B$ is a real matrix? There are complex matrices that will satisfy this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general $2\times 2$ matrix with real coefficients is similar to a matrix of the form $M = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda  & 0\\
0 & \nu\end{pmatrix}$ (where $\lambda$ and $\nu$ are either both real or complex and conjugate of one another) or $N = \begin{pmatrix}\mu & 1 \\
0 &   \mu\end{pmatrix}$ (with $\mu \in \mathbb R$)

In the first case, we have :
$$\exp(M) = \begin{pmatrix} 
e^\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & e^\nu
\end{pmatrix}$$
In the second case, we have :
$$\exp(N) = \begin{pmatrix} e^\mu & e^\mu \\ 0 & e^\mu\end{pmatrix}$$
Both of those cannot be similar to $B = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I am a little bit confused how you conclude that the eigenvalues in the diagonalizable case are conjugate. Surely they can be real and distinct.

Comment: How do you justify that these matrices are not similar?

Comment: @jokadeka055 Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues...

Comment: @Ian True, I edited the answer to take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood quite well but if the entries of your matrix B are real, you can't have negative values in exp(B).
However, if you are allowed to have the complex valued entries for B you can clearly see that for

$B=\begin{pmatrix}
i\pi & 0 \\
0 & i\pi+\ln2 
\end{pmatrix} \hspace{0.5cm} \longrightarrow{\exp(B)} \longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
\exp(i\pi) & 0 \\
0 & \exp(i\pi+\ln2 )
\end{pmatrix} \longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -2 
\end{pmatrix}$

Again I am not sure if my answer is in line with what you are asking for.